# JQuery dynamically add not working on Chrome and FireFox

Tags: jquery, html, css

I'm trying to dynamically add image and button (with click event) into existing div. The code is working on IE. But does not work on chrome and firefox. [Demo on JS](https://jsfiddle.net/yuk0n/re8svxqv/2/). Image and Button should be show on page but not show anything when i open from chrome and firefox. What wrong on my sample code?

Here is sample code.

```js
var _gimgangle = 0;
var $gnavControlContainer = $('#controlAddIn');
var $divImageContainer = $('<div></div>');
$divImageContainer.attr('id', 'gnavControlImageDivId');

var $img = $('<image></image>');
$img.attr('id', 'gnavControlImageId');

$img.attr("src",'http://i.kinja-img.com/gawker-media/image/upload/s--pEKSmwzm--/c_scale,fl_progressive,q_80,w_800/1414228815325188681.jpg').load(function () {            
 var $imgbtn = $('<button>Rotate</button>');
    $imgbtn.attr('id', 'imgbtnRotate');
    $imgbtn.attr('type', 'button');            
    $imgbtn.on('click', function () {
        //later rotate
        /*        
        _gimgangle += 90;
        $img.rotate(_gimgangle);
        _gimgangle = (_gimgangle === 360) ? 0 : _gimgangle;                
        */
        alert('Clicked...!'); //Chrome,FireFox not working, IE working
    });
    
 var $divbuttonContainer = $('<div></div>');
    $divbuttonContainer.append($imgbtn);
    $gnavControlContainer.append($divbuttonContainer);
});

$divImageContainer.append($img);
$gnavControlContainer.append($divImageContainer);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id='controlAddIn'>Here is google image</div>
```

Comment: use <img /> instead of <image></image>

Comment: i don't see this. thanks. it working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

image is not valid html tag.

```js
var _gimgangle = 0;
var $gnavControlContainer = $('#controlAddIn');
var $divImageContainer = $('<div></div>');
$divImageContainer.attr('id', 'gnavControlImageDivId');

var $img = $('<img></img>');
$img.attr('id', 'gnavControlImageId');

$img.attr("src",'http://i.kinja-img.com/gawker-media/image/upload/s--pEKSmwzm--/c_scale,fl_progressive,q_80,w_800/1414228815325188681.jpg').load(function () {            
 var $imgbtn = $('<button>Rotate</button>');
    $imgbtn.attr('id', 'imgbtnRotate');
    $imgbtn.attr('type', 'button');            
    $imgbtn.on('click', function () {
        //later rotate
        /*        
        _gimgangle += 90;
        $img.rotate(_gimgangle);
        _gimgangle = (_gimgangle === 360) ? 0 : _gimgangle;                
        */
        alert('Clicked...!'); //Chrome,FireFox not working, IE working
    });
    
 var $divbuttonContainer = $('<div></div>');
    $divbuttonContainer.append($imgbtn);
    $gnavControlContainer.append($divbuttonContainer);
});

$divImageContainer.append($img);
$gnavControlContainer.append($divImageContainer);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id='controlAddIn'>Here is google image</div>
```